# Masters programs in UK: question regarding accepting more than one offer

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-kingdom, international-students

I am an international student who is applying for a masters in the UK and has received one unconditional offer. That offer is not from not my first choice, however. I am still waiting for news other applications. My current offer would start in less than two months, so I need to respond soon. If I accept that offer now, is it okay for me to accept other offers (if they are successful) later? Most importantly: will this have any impact on my visa?

Answer (score 3):

Many, many students accept places on Master's degrees that they never turn up to. We never count our student numbers until they have actaully registered.

However, I don't know how this will affect your visa. I'm pretty sure you need to specify what university your are studying at on a student visa, and so you will need to have made a decision before last point at which you could apply for a visa and start on time.